# how to change direction of focusScope in flutter?

Tags: flutter, validation, stack, focus, direction

I have a lot of fields which some of them is required. When I press button after
`formKey.currentState!.validate()` focusing begins from the end to the beginning. How can I change the direction?

```
Stack(
                  children: [
                    SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Form(
                        key: formKey,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            EmptyLine(height: 8),
                            PropertyWidget(state: state),
                            AddressWidget(state: state),
                            SellerWidget(state: state),
                            AdvtPhotoWidget(state: state),
                            DescriptionWidget(state: state),
                            MoreInformationWidget(state: state),
                            IndicatorsWidget(state: state),
                            SourceWidget(state: state),
                            const SizedBox(height: 90)
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    BottomAlignWidget(SaveButtonWidget(
                        title: localized(context,
                            widget.update ?? false ? 'update' : 'save')!,
                        onPress: () {
                          if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                            //somecode
                          } 
                        }))
                  ],
                )
```

I have used stack for creating sticky button. For this reason when customer pressing button focused field stays under the BottomAlignWidget.

Comment: You can remove the focus by using `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();` and if want to focus on a specific field so you can assign a focusScope for that specific field.

Comment: I dont want unfocus anything, Just want change the direction. if I have name, surname and phone fields which last two is required, I want to focus to surname then phone, but in my situation it focus phone and then surname

Comment: and also dont need assign any specific field, cause customer can fill one of them then app should focus the second required field

Comment: The next focus will go when you click the keyboard next button not submit button. If you field has input type then keyboard next button will focus on next field.

Comment: yeah, but if next field is full it will focus it.but I dont want to focus full field, i just need focus only invalid fields